How can I erase a “doc-id” record on an APFS disk in macOS? Error 69845
How can I erase a doc-id?
I am on macOS 12.7 Monterey with APFS formatted SSD. Disk Utility always reports the same error:

“error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 4838, file-id 147794278 but no inode references this doc-id.”

I have only one in disk1s1 I really don't want to format my disk
I am assuming that once I find the file(s) associated associated with these errors that I can delete it and all will be okay in the world again.
I tried also Command+R but was the same.


“The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.”
So repair it and the issue should be cleared up.
Look at your screenshot. It says:

“The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.”

So repair the disk and the issue should go away. You might have to reboot into single user mode or recovery mode to allow Disk Utility to work on your hard drive if it’s a system drive. But repairing the disk should be the solution.

I did th e repair using Disk Utility in recovery mode , but continues with the samae message
